# PHP storing multiple checkbox in database

Tags: php, sql

i did my 'homework' in searching for a solution to this matter through this forum and googling, and ive tried out various ways in solving this, but i can't seem to get the value to be posted into the action file...

i understand the concept of implode / concatenating the array into a string so that it can be stored in the database, i also understand how data are parsed, but i can't seem to get this done..

PHP Form:

```
 <form name="questionnaire_1" action="test_index.php?action=send_questionnaire" method="post">
 <table>
 <tr class="row-a">   
 <td>
 2. Position<br />
 <i>( You may choose more than one option for this question)</i>
 </td>
<td colspan="6">
<label> <input type="checkbox" name="position[]" value="1"  /> Project Leader (External)    </label><br />
<label><input type="checkbox" name="position[]" value="2"  /> Project Leader (Internal)
</label><br />
<label><input type="checkbox" name="position[]" value="3" />Project Member (External)
</label> <br />
<label><input type="checkbox" name="position[]" value="4" /> Project Member (Internal)
</label><br />
<label> <input type="checkbox" name="position[]" value="5" />Others (Please Specify)</label>

<input name="position_specify" type="text" size="40" maxlength="40" />
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

PHP Action:

```
if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) 
{       
$position = mysql_prep($_POST['position']);
$allPosition = implode (",", $position);
}
etc ...
```

the position_specify input has no problem... only having problem with the checkbox... the database takes in varchar(255) for the position.. i really do not know how to solve this..

much help is appreciated, thank you & God bless!

Comment: Is the list of checkboxes fixed?

Comment: sorry, i dont quiet get what you mean... do you mean that the values are fixed?

Comment: What is `mysql_prep()`?  Is it documented to work recursively on arrays?  Also, why are you not modeling this in the database as a one-to-many relationship?

Comment: oh sorry, mysql_prep() removes any magic quote effects so mysql_real_escape_string can do the work

as for the one-to-many relationship part.. care to explain more? i dont see how this is not a 1-to-m rel.

Comment: why not implode first, then do mysql_prep, maybe mysql_prep doesn't actually handle arrays?

Comment: THANKS miki! that worked out... i was cracking my head for an hour plus now... haha

Answer (score 0):

You may have a look at bitwise operators. So in otherwords five the first checkbox the value 1 then rhe second value 2 and 3rd value 4. So count in bits. So when submitting the form add all the values together by adding all the values of the checked checkboxes. And then store ome value in the db.

To check if the checkbox was ticked do the following

```
If($box & 1){ echo 'checkbox 1 is checked';}
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible reference to source of `mysql_prep()` function: http://forums.devnetwork.net/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=81234 . Note that it ends up passing an array to `mysql_real_escape_string()` which doubtless converts the array to the string `"Array"`, which is then stored in the database. As [miki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/879359/miki) posted in the comments above, imploding before escaping should solve your problem.